# How can one dynamically select which network interface to use to make a connection?

Tags: 14.04, networking, steam

I'll start off by explaining my set-up.

I have an Ubuntu workstation (14.04) which has two connections to two different switches, on the 10.1.x.x network and 10.2.x.x network respectively (I will call them switch 1 and 2). I then have a Windows 10 VM which is also connected to switch 1 and switch 2. The Ubuntu workstation and the Windows VM can ping eachother on both networks. Internet can also work on both networks.

Now here is what I want to do. I want to be able to dynamically select which network is used when I'm doing something that requires a connection between these two machines. For example, when I use Steam's streaming functionality to stream a game hosted on the Windows VM from the Ubuntu workstation, it currently automatically uses switch 2. I want to be able to somehow dynamically select which network to use.

I have a vague idea that this could be done with Open Vswitch, but I'm not entirely sure. Does anyone have any suggestions to how I could approach this problem?

Comment: Maybe iptables. I believe you can use on net or the other depending on the traffic type. Or maybe just changing your routing table with `route` to redirect all the traffic.